# rails controller's action / disable concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, race-condition

I have an endpoint that receives a confirmation from our payment service.

However, this payment service pings twice, so - given how we've implemented this - we end up with two orders confirmations.

I'm not looking to discuss how we designed this part (it will be improved) - I'd like to understand how to set things up in order to make sure an action could lock any concurrent others until it completes.

Or at least to understand what would be the starting point to treat such an issue.

The duplication comes from this action:

```
def export
  return head(:ok) if @order.reload.state == 'complete'
  post_data(data)
  @order.update(state: :complete)
  head(:ok)
end

private

def post_data(data)
  Curl.post("#{SHOP_URL}/orders.json", data.to_json) do |http|
    http.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    http.headers['Accept'] = '*/*'
  end
end
```

If export is called twice, and the order not refreshed, I end up with two confirmations, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If there is some unique parameter in the request you receive, you can use that to check of it has already been processed. Not sure if i got your question right though.

Comment: edited my answer accordingly, hope it'll clarify

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, unless it's the result of a race condition? If both `export` calls are fired at once, `post_data(data)` might be getting called both times before your record is updated. I'm not sure of a solution for this, and imagine the best way will indeed be to fix up the payment service (although I know that's not what you wanted to hear here).

Comment: JFYI, "enforce concurrency" means the exact opposite of what you're trying to do. You're looking to prevent/disable concurrency.

Comment: A locking mechanism of some kind can be useful here. For example: [redis-lock](https://github.com/mlanett/redis-lock).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev felt bad before writing as i was feeling like this was a bad naming mistake. thx